# Energy inequality on this $3 \times 3$ linear system

Tags: matrices, inequality, solution-verification, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be the matrix

$$A= \begin{pmatrix}  2 & -1 & 0\\
-1 & 3 & -1 \\
0& -1 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$$
and $B$ a given vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Denote $U=(u_1,u_2,u_3)^t$ the solution of $AU=B$ and

$$U_1= \begin{pmatrix}  u_1\\
0\\
0\end{pmatrix}, \ U_2= \begin{pmatrix}  0\\
u_2\\
0\end{pmatrix}, \ U_3= \begin{pmatrix}  0\\
0\\
u_3\end{pmatrix}.$$

Also denote $F(X)= \frac{1}{2} AX \cdot X - B \cdot X$ the corresponding functional of the linear system which is minimized by $U$.

**I would like to prove the following inequality** :

$$F(U) \geq F(U_1) + F(U_3).$$

I computed the difference, using the decomposition $U=U_1 + U_2 + U_3$ and the fact that $A$ is symmetric :

\begin{align*} 
F(U) - F(U_1) - F(U_3) & = A (U_1+U_3) \cdot U_2 - B \cdot U_2\\
&= A(U-U_2) \cdot U_2 - B \cdot U_2\\
&= A A^{-1} B \cdot U_2 - AU_2 \cdot U_2- B \cdot U_2 \text{ using the linear system}\\
&= -A U_2 \cdot U_2 \leq 0
\end{align*}
since the matrix $A$ is symmetric and defined positively.

Finaly, **I proved the exact inverse of the inequality I was looking for**... Did I made a mistake somewhere ? Furthermore, I only used that $A$ was in $S_3^{++}(\mathbb{R})$, so I guess this result is true for any matrix in $S_3^{++}(\mathbb{R})$ (**Update : I did use the values in the matrix to get the first equality**)? Could it be generalized to $n \times n$ dimension matrices ? Is there any interpretation to this result ?

Comment: Your first equality looks a bit suspicious, I feel like there should be quite a few more terms. E.g., where did $AU_1 \cdot U_3$ go?

Comment: Actually, I used the values in my matrix : $$A U_1 = \begin{pmatrix}  2 u_1\\
-u_1\\
0\end{pmatrix}$$ so that the scalar product with $$U_3 = \begin{pmatrix}  0\\
0\\
u_3\end{pmatrix}$$ is zero, @Rammus .

Comment: Ahh sorry, misread the question, I was thinking $A$ was an arbitrary PSD matrix!

Comment: I checked your calculations and they seem correct to me. Also, I did a quick random search and your conjecture that this extends to all positive definite matrices is not true, counterexamples are fairly common.